# Find hourly gaps in date ranges .NET

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an availibility class

```
public class AvailabilityDto 
{
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

And I am trying to create a report that will find gaps within the availabilities.
Given a list of the availability class, and a start and end date to search between. I am trying to find gaps within the availabilities

It is to see if anyone is on call outside of the usual office hours of 9-5.

Here is my current implementation which is very inefficient and not working :

```
    foreach(var entry in rota) {

     //get all items from the list that are available out of office hours
    //and order them by start time

     var outOfHoursAvailibilities = entry.Availabilities
      .Where(m => m.EndDateTime.Hour <= 9 || m.StartDateTime.Hour >= 17)
      .OrderBy(m => m.StartDateTime)
      .ToList();

     var i = 0;

     while (i < outOfHoursAvailibilities.Count) {

      var currentStart = outOfHoursAvailibilities[i];
      var next = outOfHoursAvailibilities[i + 1];

      //if first ends before second starts,
      if (currentStart.EndDateTime < next.StartDateTime)  
      {
       //this means we have a gap -- until the next next one
       currentStart = next;
       i++;
       next = outOfHoursAvailibilities[i + 1];

       var missingAvailabilty = new AvailabilityDto {
        StartDateTime = currentStart.EndDateTime,
         EndDateTime = next.StartDateTime,    
       };

       gaps.Add(missingAvailabilty);

      }

      i++;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Couldn't you do this with the database directly to return the proper data?  Basically, do a where not exists or something along those lines?  We need more information about your structure.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it's to exclude office hours as there is staff in the office

Comment: Shouldn't "on call outside of the usual office hours of 9-5" be represented as: `Where(m => !(m.StartDateTime.Hour >= 9 && m.EndDateTime.Hour <= 17)`? - This expression will also get those calls that started earlier but ended during office hours, and those that started during but ended later than usual office hours.

Comment: The usual method that have been used for a long time (by ATT&T Bell Systems) is to bin the calls by time period.  So create a table of 5 minute time periods from midnight to midnight.  Then go through list of calls and put into the 5 minute periods.  The time periods with 0 calls are the gaps.  A single call may fall into multiple 5 minute time periods.  This algorithm often is used to get Trunk Line usage to see if more trunk lines are needed to prevent busy singles.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `currentStart = next`, you overwrite the object that has the `StartDateTime` of the missing availability. When you instantiate the new `AvailabilityDto`, you are setting the values as the next availability, instead of the current gap you found. I think you don't need to set the current with next.

Try this (without setting `next` to `currentStart`):

```
if (currentStart.EndDateTime < next.StartDateTime)  
{
    var missingAvailabilty = new AvailabilityDto {
        StartDateTime = currentStart.EndDateTime,
        EndDateTime = next.StartDateTime,    
    };

    gaps.Add(missingAvailabilty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you order your availabilities by `StartDateTime` and then `EndDateTime` and simply track the latest end time as you loop over them you can easily achieve what you want. If you encounter a start time that is later than current latest end time then you have found a gap. Here I am implementing it as an extension method:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<AvailabilityDto> FindAvailabilityGaps(this IEnumerable<AvailabilityDto> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        var sorted = source.OrderBy(x => x.StartDateTime).ThenBy(x => x.EndDateTime);

        using (var e = sorted.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!e.MoveNext())
            {
                yield break;
            }

            var latestEndTime = e.Current.EndDateTime;

            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                if (e.Current.StartDateTime > latestEndTime)
                {
                    yield return new AvailabilityDto
                    {
                        StartDateTime = latestEndTime,
                        EndDateTime = e.Current.StartDateTime
                    };
                }

                if (e.Current.EndDateTime > latestEndTime)
                {
                    latestEndTime = e.Current.EndDateTime;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
var outOfHoursAvailibilities = 
    entry
    .Availabilities
    .Where(m => m.EndDateTime.Hour <= 9 || m.StartDateTime.Hour >= 17)
    .FindAvailabilityGaps();
```

It is not clear to me if you are using Entity Framework or some other ORM in your example. If so you will want to call `AsEnumerable` before calling the extension method because the LINQ provider will not be able to translate `FindAvailabilityGaps` to SQL. So like this:

```
var outOfHoursAvailibilities = 
    entry
    .Availabilities
    .Where(m => m.EndDateTime.Hour <= 9 || m.StartDateTime.Hour >= 17)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .FindAvailabilityGaps();
```

Of course if you don't want to use an extension method you can just take the contents of the method above and use it any way you like.

As an aside, I don't think your predicate to exclude office hours is going to achieve what you want. I think @5ar's comment is correct:

```
m => !(m.StartDateTime.Hour >= 9 || m.EndDateTime.Hour <= 17)
```